# git push only one commit from branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push, git-commit

I have a commit `C1` in `master`. I have branched out after that and have made commit `C2` in branch. Now I want to push only commit `C2` to `master`.(`C1` is not yet ready to be pushed) How to do that..

```
    C2(branch)
  /
|
|
C1 (master)
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

you can use [git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) and specify the commit ids that you want to merge

```
git cherry-pick C2
```

will merge only commit C2 into the master branch

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your wording is a bit confusing: when talking about `push`, there's always a remote involved. So you don't `git push` from `branch` to `master` but to `origin/master`.

If I understood you correctly, here's how to push exactly one commit from your branch `branch` to `origin/master`

Check out a fresh local branch `tmp-for-pushing` from your last pushed revision:

```
git fetch origin && git checkout -b tmp-for-pushing origin/master
```

Cherry-pick `C2` into this branch:

```
git cherry-pick C2
```

Publish this single commit:

```
git push origin tmp-for-pushing:master
```

**By now, you updated your remote but we need to clean up again.**

Checkout master again:

```
git checkout master
```

Throw away your temporary branch

```
git branch -D tmp-for-pushing
```

Rebase master onto your updated `origin/master`

```
git fetch origin && git rebase origin/master
```

Rebase C2 onto your updated `master` (if `C2` was the only commit there, `C2` will equal `master` after this:

```
git checkout branch && git rebase master
```